# Iteration on a variable of type: Observable <{[key: string]: Thread}>

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to this forum. I've been blocking my problem for several days.
I would like to create a loop to iterate every object that I have in my collection.

Here is my variable:

```
threads: Observable<{ [key: string]: Thread }>;
```

And my function where I want to create a loop forEach or for:

```
findById(threadId: string) : Thread {
let foundThread: Thread = null;

this.threads.forEach(
  (thread: Thread): void => {
    if (thread.id === threadId) {
      foundThread = thread;
    }
  },
  null
);
return foundThread;
}
```

But I have this error :

```
TS2345:Argument of type '(thread: Thread) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { [key: string]: Thread; }) => void'. Types of parameters 'thread' and 'value' are incompatible. Type '{ [key: string]: Thread; }' is not assignable to type 'Thread'. Property 'id' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: Thread; }'
```

I tried another solution, but it does not work anymore :

```
findById(threadId: string) : Thread {
let foundThread: Thread = null;
for (let thread in this.threads) {
  if (thread.id === threadId) {
    foundThread = thread;
  }
}
return foundThread;
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

UPDATE :

Here is my function :

```
getThreadFromSubscription(threadId: string): Observable<Thread> {
return this.threads
  .map( (threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
    for (let key in threadDictionary) {
      if (threadDictionary[key].id == threadId)
        return threadDictionary[key];
    }
  });
}
```

And here is the function where I want to use the varaible returned by the function:

```
addNewMessage(objMessage: any) : void {
objMessage.thread = this.threadService.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id)
  .subscribe ((thread: Thread) => {
    if (objMessage.thread != null) {
      const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
      this.addMessage(newMessage);
    }
    else {
      const newThread: Thread = new Thread();
    }
  });
}
```

I'm not sure I understand. Does my variable 'objMessage.thread' take the thread value returned using 'getThreadFromSubscription' ?
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: What version of Angular?

Comment: It's the Angular 4 version

Comment: did you try using this.threads.map((thread)=>{if (thread.id === threadId) {
      foundThread = thread;
    }})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`threads` is not a dictionary or a list that you can iterate though. Instead, it is a stream of events (an `Observable`). The type of events emitted from the stream is a `dictionary<string, Thread>`.

What you are saying, is that every now and then, you will have a new dictionary coming from your `threads` Observable. You can apply the `.map` operator to your Observable to do some processing on each dictionary that is emitted:

```
this.threads.map((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
    \\ do some processing on the threadDictionary
});
```

To look through each key of the dictionary, you can iterate through it like this:

```
for (let key in threadDictionary) {
    if (threadDictioanry[key].id == threadId)
        foundThread = threadDictionary[key];
}
```

Since `threads` is an observable, you'll need to subscribe to it somewhere to consume the values it emits. You can modify your function to return an `Observable<Thread>` that you can subscribe to in order to get the correct thread when your original `threads` stream emits a value:

```
getThreadFromSubscription(threadId: string): Observable<Thread> {
    return this.threads.map((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
        for (let key in threadDictionary) {
            if (threadDictionary[key].id == threadId)
                return threadDictionary[key];
        }
    });
}
```

You can subscribe to this like so:

```
this.getThreadFromSubscription('1').subscribe((thread: Thread) => {
    this.processMyThread(thread);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, thanks to you I understand the terms 'Observable' and '.subscribe' better.

Only, can you take a look at my post that I updated because I am not sure about using the correct method to assign to my variable 'objMessage.thread' the value of the thread returned by the function ' getThreadFromSubscription '.

Comment: _Does my variable 'objMessage.thread' take the thread value returned using 'getThreadFromSubscription' ?_  No. When you subscribe to `getThreadFromSubscription` you are going to be getting a series of Threads. Each time a Thread comes in, you assign it to the variable `thread` and can act on it. So you would want to assign `objMessage.thread = thread` inside the subscription.

Comment: But I should have said from the beginning that I'm concerned about how you are using `threads: Observable<{ [key: string]: Thread }>;`. I think your real problem is there. That is only valid if you have something that is returning a series of `Dictionary<string, Thread>`, which seems unlikely. More likely, you have some service which is returning a series of `Thread`s, and that is what you want to deal with. [This resource](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) was really helpful when I started learning about Observables.

Comment: Do you know why when I am testing the debugging Angular to test this function like this :
`ng.probe($0).componentInstance.threadService.__proto__.getThreadFromSubscription('tEcho')`
It puts this errror : 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`